# Prove $|x_{k+1}-x_{*}|\le \rho|x_k-x_{*}||x_{k-1}-x_{*}|$ is equivalent with $|x_{k+1}-x_{*}|\le \delta|x_k-x_{*}|^p$, where $1<p<2$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

The definition of convergence in super-linear is $$|x_{k+1}-x_{*}|\le \rho|x_k-x_{*}||x_{k-1}-x_{*}|$$

I am asked to prove this is equivalent to $$|x_{k+1}-x_{*}|\le \delta|x_k-x_{*}|^p$$ where $1<p<2$.

Intuitively, it seems right to me.

However, I have no clue how to rigorously prove it. Could someone kindly help? Thanks!

Comment: Then you just have to apply my now deleted comment...

Comment: @Did I think your comment is right. Do you mind post it as an answer and I will accept it. Very sorry about the typo.

Comment: Yes my comment is (was) right, thanks.

Comment: @Did Thanks. I am stuck after getting $a_n, b_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers. Could you help provide a hint? Thanks so much!

Comment: Hmmm... By the way: if $u_{k+1}=\rho u_ku_{k-1}$ for every $k$ then indeed $u_{k+1}\leqslant\delta (u_k)^\varphi$ for every $k$, where $\varphi=\frac12(1+\sqrt5)$, but if $u_{k+1}\leqslant\rho u_ku_{k-1}$ for every $k$ then nothing guarantees that there exists some finite $C$ and $p>1$ such that $u_{k+1}\leqslant C (u_k)^p$ for every $k$. The trouble is that if $u_{k+1}=\rho u_ku_{k-1}$ for most $k$ but $u_{k+1}\ll u_ku_{k-1}$ for every $k$ in some sparse $K$ then $u_{k+2}\leqslant\rho u_{k+1}u_{k}$ will not prevent $u_{k+2}/(u_{k+1})^p$ to be unbounded. Sure about the exercise?